# Windows malloc issue?

Tags: c++, malloc

In Windows (Visual Studio C++ 2010) I'm trying to do a simple string copy. Here's my code:

```
char * filename;
(...)
filename = (char *) malloc(wcslen(argv[(i + 1)]) + 1);
wcscpy((wchar_t *)filename, argv[i + 1]);
wprintf(L"Filename is: %s", filename);
```

And the program crashes if my argv[i + 1] if bigger than 14. If it is 14 or less it runs fine. See bellow.

```
C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\Release>test.exe -f 12345678901234 aa asas asas
First Argument  argv[1]   -f
Argc = 6
Filename is: 12345678901234
```

What's the gotcha here? What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Please decide on the programming language

Comment: malloc .. * sizeof(wchar_t)`

Comment: @Olaf - How did you decide that it is C++. Visual stuio C++ does contain a C compiler

Comment: @EdHeal I'd guess based on that the return value of `malloc` is cast explicitly which is a bad idea in C, but mandatory in C++.

Comment: ... But in C++ should `new` be used? Or `std::wstring`?

Comment: If it's C++, why not simply `std::wstring filename = argv[i+1];`?

Comment: @EdHeal: Occams razor: 1) Mentioned C++, added c++ tag, casts `void *` which is not necessary & discouraged in C. 2) If it is wrong, OP shall change, but not add both.

Comment: @EdHeal: You still wonder ppl use C coding style in C++? You're longer here than me and still an optimist:-).

Comment: Isn't for wide "strings" the `0`-terminator as well 2 `char`s wide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realise that `wcslen()` returns the number of wide characters in the string, not the number of bytes that it occupies. And `malloc()` requires a number of bytes...

So you need to multiply the *number* of wide characters by the *size* of a wide character before passing it to `malloc()`:

`filename = (char *) malloc( (wcslen(argv[(i + 1)]) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));`

But then, you're typecasting it to `(char *)`. If `argv` is declared as `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`, then `wcslen()` is the wrong function to use anyway: you need `strlen()`.

Comment: Why does he not get a type warning then? Is MSVC++ really that bad (or just bad defaults)?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, still learning. My argv is declared as wchar_t too.
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])

Comment: _@JohnBurger_ You don't need to address the OP namely in every post. Such is considered _noise_.

Comment: `argv` probably is declared as `wchar_t *argv[]`, but he's declared `filename` as `char *` and using typecasting all over the place. He makes the mistake many people do: a `char` is a `char` is a `wchar_t` - and they're all the same size. Nope!

Comment: I just checked, no warning. Is it possible to increase the warning level?

Comment: @flexow There are no warnings because you applied C-style casts all over the place, shutting the compiler up.  Remove all of those casts, and then you will receive warnings, if not outright errors.

Comment: Yes, I need to declare filename as wchar_t too. Thanks.

Comment: @flexow And BTW, if you find yourself casting pointer to strings like this, take a step back and review your code.  You should never need to cast pointer to strings -- doing this is a sign that you're trying to "convert" one string type to another, and casting does not convert character types.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I would go further - think twice before [casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_%28fishing%29). Like fishing you do not want to hook up something that you are not expecting to catch

Comment: :) Thanks for the advice. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++ then do it the C++ way i.e.

Dump

```
char * filename;
(...)
filename = (char *) malloc(wcslen(argv[(i + 1)]) + 1);
wcscpy((wchar_t *)filename, argv[i + 1]);
wprintf(L"Filename is: %s", filename);
```

and replace it with

```
std::wstring filename = argv[i+1];
wcout << L"FIlename is: " << filename;
```

and `main` is replaced by

```
wmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[ ]);
```

Comment: Why you need `filename` is another matter and a question left open for the readers to ponder,.

Comment: `cout <<` should be `std::wcout <<`

Comment: Correct - well spotted.